# Symfony 2.4 LiipImagineBundle

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I installed LiipImagineBundle, it looks like the bundle was installed correct. In my template i add the line:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/codecatsfront/images/python-bg.png') | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" alt="...">
```

but there is server error for this url:
http://pc.t/app_dev.php/media/cache/my_thumb/bundles/codecatsfront/images/python-bg.png

my python-bg.png is src/CodeCats/FrontBundle/Resources/public/images/ linked to web/codecatsfront/images.

I also tried command:

```
app/console liip:imagine:cache:resolve php-bg.png
```

and it works, my additional config for this bundle:

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
       default:
          web_path: ~

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        my_thumb:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

Comment: What does the error look like? What web server have you installed?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error, Apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What error message do you recieve? maybe what is written in the apache log files?

Comment: I havent found it in logs, maybe I should configure htaccess?

Comment: Do you have an apache configuration for static assets?

Comment: Where can I find informations about the config?

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of the "asset()" function.

```
<img src="{{ 'bundles/codecatsfront/images/python-bg.png' | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" alt="...">
```

Does it fix it ?